# AS3 get children of movieclip in library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, movieclip

So I have this movievlip in my library, which is an instance of `TestClass`. There are four other movieclips in the parent movieclip. This is `TestClass`:

```
package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class TestClass extends MovieClip{

        public function TestClass() {
            for(var i:int = 0; i < numChildren; i++){
                trace(getChildAt(i));
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

However, this traces `null` four times, while it should trace `[object MovieClip]` right? Also, when I set the names of the movieclips under the accessibility tab and then use `getChildByName('test')`, it still traces `null`.

My question is: how can I get specific children from a movieclip in my library? For instance, when there are two children, I only want to get the child with the name `test`

Comment: That should work. Are you sure something else is not tracing "null"?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I tried to reproduce your issue.

1. I created a parent MovieClip and set a linkage name as "TestClass". Also, I added four child MovieClips to the `TestClass`.

[image]

2. I created TestClass.as file with the same code.

In the output tab I see four `[object MovieClip]` lines. I don't know why you got `null`. Can you provide FLA file?

---

Why you set a name of child in the accessibility tab? You should set name in the "instance name" of properties panel.

[image]

So you can address to child by its name: `child_1` in my case. `trace(child_1);` returns `[object MovieClip]`.

Comment: hmmm, weird. When I trace the children from the timeline, I don't get `null`. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: @Jonan can you upload your FLA file.

Comment: Nevermind, I now know what's wrong. In my actual code, `TestClass` extends another class, and I called `super()` in `TestClass`'s constructor *after* I tried to get the children